# Android: Create unique string for file name

Tags: android, random

I'm doing an android application for image viewer. This app will download the image, and store them in a cache folder.

So, in the cache folder, the image file name must be unique. Currently, I use String.hashCode() to generate the file name.

Are there any other better ways to get unique string?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [java.util.UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html). Look at [randomUUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) that generates a so-called [Universally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

I don't really understand how you intend to generate a “unique” value with String.hashCode. On what string do you call hashCode? hashCode's purpose is not to generate unique IDs... It's meant to generate a [hash code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for a string, so if the strings themselves are not unique, the hash codes won't be either.

Comment: Thank you for answer it. Actually, what i did is to store the online image to the local. Because each image has unique url, I use url.hashcode to generate the file name. I just wonder if there will be a performance issue to use hashcode to do it. So I want to know the common way how you save the cache file, and make them unique.

Comment: That is the whole purpose, to be able to get a unique and specific ID for a specific url. If you create random UUID then you will have to maintain a map of urls and IDs. But hashcode will always return the same id for a particular id.

Comment: String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");

Answer (score 23):

Use [java.util.UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html).

```
  String uniqueString = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

ChrisJ suggestion to use UUID.randomUUID() is a good alternative; but i'd prefer to have the cache backed up by a database table:

```
ID (PK) | original filename | original URL
```

and then using the primary key as filename in cache dir.

If you plan to have lots of files, having a directory tree structure like:

```
0 
+--- 0
     +---- 01.jpg
     +---- 02.jpg
     +---- ...
     +---- 0f.jpg
+--- 1
     +---- 10.jpg
     +---- ...
     +---- cc.jpg
```

after converting the primary key to hex could also be a cleaner solution, but you will have to decide a left padding for the filenames, which will be a function of the directory tree depth and the number of files per leaf directory.

Comment: It's implementable. But I already has caching them in different way. And I only cache the file after it was stored in local completely.