# How to name recorded file uniquely?

Tags: android

I am building audio recorder app. Problem is i want to generate unique name for audio like audio_1.wav,audio_2.wav and so on to avoid replacing of new audio with old one. Maybe my question seems to be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126559/android-create-unique-string-for-file-name) but what i want is different. i want my files name in order of audio1.wav, audio2.wav and so on.

```
pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "audio.wav";


                setupMediaRecorder();
                try{
                    mediarcorder.prepare();
                    mediarcorder.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**setupMediaRecorder()**

```
        mediarcorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediarcorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediarcorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediarcorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediarcorder.setOutputFile(pathSave);
```

When i record new audio it name should be different from previous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Create unique string for file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126559/android-create-unique-string-for-file-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend including a time stamp in the file name.  You can get the current time with:

```java
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then convert that into a string and append it to your file names.

Comment: Thanks for giving me an alternative. I will use this when i didn't find what i want.